# How do i prove this trigonometric expression?

Tags: trigonometry

How do you prove this?
$${(1-2\sin^2A)^2 \over \cos^4A-\sin^4A} = {2\cos^2A - 1}$$

Comment: Express everything in terms of $u = \cos A$, and go from there...

Comment: I don't.${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(1-2\sin^2(A))^2}{\cos^4(A)-\sin^4(A)}
&=\frac{(1-2\sin^2(A))^2}{(1-\sin^2(A))^2-\sin^4(A)}\\
&=\frac{(1-2\sin^2(A))^2}{1-2\sin^2(A)}\\
&=1-2\sin^2(A)\\[9pt]
&=1-2(1-\cos^2(A))\\[9pt]
&=2\cos^2(A)-1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Recall the following expressions for $\cos(2A)$:
$$\color{magenta}{\cos(2A)} = \cos^2(A) - \sin^2(A) = \color{red}{2\cos^2(A)-1} = \color{blue}{1-2\sin^2(A)} = \color{green}{\cos^4(A) - \sin^4(A)}$$
Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{\left(\color{blue}{1-2\sin^2(A)}\right)^2}{\color{green}{\cos^4(A) - \sin^4(A)}} = \dfrac{\color{magenta}{\cos^2(2A)}}{\color{magenta}{\cos(2A)}} = \color{magenta}{\cos(2A)} = \color{red}{2\cos^2(A)-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

${(1-2\sin^2A)^2 \over \cos^4A-\sin^4A}$

$cos^22A \over \ (cos^2A-\sin^2A)(cos^2A+\sin^2A) $

$cos^22A \over \ (cos^2A-\sin^2A) \ *\ 1 $

$cos^22A \over \ (cos2A) $

cos2A

${2\cos^2A - 1}$

Answer (score 0):

Observe that we need to eliminate $\sin A$

So using $\sin^2A=1-\cos^2A,$

$1-2\sin^2A=1-2(1-\cos^2A)=2\cos^2A-1$

and $\cos^4A-\sin^4A=(\cos^2A-\sin^2A)(\cos^2A+\sin^2A)=1\cdot\{\cos^2A-(1-\cos^2A)\}=2\cos^2A-1$

or $\cos^4A-\sin^4A=\cos^4A-(1-\cos^2A)^2=2\cos^2A-1$